# Handling multiple 400 errors on one functionality

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

Hi I need to handle multiple 400 errors under one functionality, but I can't seem to get it to work in Angular.

The code below should work, but I can't get the LOCKED_ERROR part from the response in Angular's HttpErrorResponse.

BadRequestException.java

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends ApiException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4043436953989551177L;

    public BadRequestException(String errorCode, String message) {
        super(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errorCode, message);
    }
    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString(), message);
    }
}
```

ShiftWorkerLockedException.java

```
public class ShiftWorkerLockedException extends BadRequestException {
    public ShiftWorkerLockedException() { super("LOCKED_ERROR", "Shift worker is locked."); }
}
```

This is the angular code:

```
this.shiftService.assignJobToWorker(worker,
      job,
      startTime.format(),
      endTime.format()).subscribe(
        (data) => {
        this.toastr.success('Töö määratud kasutajale ' + worker.user.name + ' algusega ' + startTime.format('HH:mm'));
        this.refreshShiftWorkers.emit();
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.refreshShiftWorkers.emit();
      }
    );
```

And this is the error response without the custom errorCode:

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: "Shift worker is locked."
path: "/shift-jobs/101/worker"
status: 400
timestamp: "2019-08-16T09:32:30.627+0000"
```

I want to use toasters to print out errors in different languages, depending on the custom status code, but I can't get the right response, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the @ControllerAdvice annotation from

> springframework.web.bind.annotation

package. It allows you to define a class that may intercept your exceptions. It looks something like this:

```
        // If you want to add more types of exceptions to handle, you can add 
        // extra methods like this one in this class
        @ControllerAdvice
        public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

            // With this annotation you specify the type of class that you will handle
            // and you add your custom response
            @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
            public @ResponseBody
            ResponseEntity<CustomErrorResponse> handleApiException(ApiException exception) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(new CustomErrorResponse(exception.getMessage()), exception.getStatus());
            }
}
```

So, What you could do is to create a custom class that contains whatever you want in your response, so you can access the data you included in that class as an object in your Angular side. Something similar to this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
class CustomErrorResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6883129706029524672L;

    // Use here whatever you need, in this case is a set of Strings
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<String> messages = new HashSet<>();

    ErrorResponse(Set<String> messages) {
        this.messages.addAll(messages);
    }

    ErrorResponse(String message) {
        messages.add(message);
    }
}
```

Official docs on this stuff is really good so i'd recommend taking and look on it